# Regarding portletSession

Tags: java

Hi I am using following snippet code for getting the session in portal server once it will set but I am getting result as null

## **Code:--**

```
public void viewSession(WebAppAccess webAppAccess) throws PortletException,
                    IOException {
            String sessionValue="userDefinedValue";
            try {


                    PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) webAppAccess
                                    .getHttpServletRequest().getAttribute(
                                                    Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST);
                    PortletSession session = portletRequest.getPortletSession();
                    session.setAttribute("application",
                                    sessionValue, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
                    log.Info("AFTER SET SESSION VALUE:----"
                                    + session.getAttribute("application"));
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                    log.Error("error is:---", e);
            }
    }
```

But, in result I am getting null value

## **output:--**

AFTER SET SESSION VALUE:----null

please give solution

Comment: Are you sure that `sessionValue` is not null?

Comment: thank you for reply..yes its not null value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using scope `PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE`:

```
session.getAttribute("application", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Comment: @user3060343, you will find check to left of my answer, just below the down arrow.

Comment: aravind one more question what is diffenent between request.getsESSION(TRUE) and request.getsESSION(false)

Comment: @user3060343, catch up [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59701/java-session)